# Can't get Value and DisplayMember from CheckedListBoxControl bound to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, checkedlistbox

The question has been asked before on StackOverflow so you might think it's a duplicate, but I've tried a number of solutions, but I'm still stuck.

I have a WinForms CheckedListBoxControl bound to a LINQ query and I fail to get the Value and DisplayMembers.

Below are some tries to get the Value and DisplayMember values:

```
 var avail = from c in dc.CostCenters
                       select new { Item = c.CostCenterID, 
                               Description = c.CostCenterID + ": " + c.Description };
                myList.DataSource = avail;
                myList.DisplayMember = "Description";


        //Retrieval:
        foreach (var item in myList.CheckedItems)
        {
            DataRowView row = item as DataRowView; //Try 1: row is empty
            string displayMember = item["Description"]; //Try 2: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
            var x = item[0]; //Try 3: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
            row3 = ((DataRowView)myList.CheckedItems[item]).Row; //Try 5 million: Compile error - invalid arguments
        }
```

Comment: what `item.GetType()`? You use standard [CheckedListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.110).aspx) or some third-party libs with controls?

Comment: I've tried both the standard one, and the DevExpress one.  I don't mind which one works.  For the purpose of this post I'll have to look at the standard control as this is not a devExpress forum.

Comment: item.GetType() =  Name = "<>f__AnonymousTypeb6`2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just want to get/display your ValueMembers/DisplayMembers:
From the sample you provide I assume you get a `IEnumerable<dynamic>` from your linq query. I have converted it for my test scenario to `List<dynamic>`:

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { Item = 1, Description = "1: Item1"},
    new { Item = 2, Description = "2: Item2"}
};
```

just add a BindingSource to the CheckedListBox:

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource(list, null);

checkedListBox1.DataSource = bindingSource;
checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Item";
checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
```

When you have selected your items and you want to check it:

```
var checkedItems = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems;
foreach (dynamic checkedItem in checkedItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine("valuemember: " + checkedItem.Item);
    // or whatever code you have
}
```

Hope this helps!